# Confusion in Venn Diagram.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm learning Sets and Relation with myself. Right now I am trying to understand Venn Diagram. I am little bit confused in a problem. Please have a look at the image. [image: Image 1] 

In the picture I have taken an small example of three sets A, B and C. 

 $A={1,2,3,4} $ 
 $B={3,4,5,8} $ In the picture I forget to write 8 
 $C= { 3,4,5,6,7} $

 and drawn Venn Diagram of **A∩B∩C**. The Full Shaded portion represent A∩B∩C i.e **{3,4}** but also it is representing A∩B, A∩C and B∩C. I am confused in what other area that is indicated by lines will denote. Please help. Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The top one is everything in A and B but not C, which in this case is an empty set.  If you were to add 8 to A and B then 8 would appear here.

The one on the left is also an empty set; it is everything in A and C but not B.

The one on the right is {5}, since it is everything in B and C ({3,4,5}) but not A (removing {3,4}), leaving just {5}.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: The only difference this makes to my answer is that I would have to use a number other than 8 in my first sentence.  For example "if you were to add 27 to A and B then 27 would appear here", and to avoid further confusion, do not use 27 in future edits.

Comment: And what the shaded plus the area indicated by line will denote as a whole. For example the top one with shaded portion..

Comment: If the area Indicated with lines are empty set then it shouldn't be joined in the Diagram. I think my Diagram is wrong. What you think?

Comment: The shaded area plus the indicated area would be the intersection of two of the variables, for example the top area plus the central would be A∩B.  I don't think your diagram is incorrect, unless of course you only wanted non-empty sets showing, in which case it would need redrawing as in Mankind's answer.  Your diagram is a correct representation of a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, we have $A\cap B = \{3,4\}$, $A\cap C = \{3,4\}$, and $B\cap C = \{3,4,5\}$. Thus $A\cap B$ and $A\cap C$ are actually the same as $A\cap B\cap C$.

The reason why this is happening is that $B$ is a *subset* of $C$: All elements of $B$ are also elements of $C$. Thus your diagram does not represent your example very well, which might be what is confusing you. The following picture is more representative:

[image]

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: What if B is not subset of C. I'm editing the question.

Comment: @YogeshTripathi, well, in your edited question $B$ is still a subset of $C$, but what are you asking exactly? Are you asking about $A\cap B$, $A\cap C$, and $B\cap C$, or are you maybe asking about the parts of $A\cap B$, $A\cap C$, and $B\cap C$ that are not contained in $A\cap B\cap C$?

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake. I wanted to write B= {  3,4,5,8}